# C# Displaying different UI elements depending on user choice

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, dropdown

I am learning C# GUI development using visual studio. I have come accross a dilema. So I have a somewhat basic UI where a user can make a choice from a list of about 30 radio buttons. Depending on which radio button is picked upon button click -> I want to display 2 dropdowns with specific values inside it.

So if you imagine there will be a total of 60 dropdowns in total but only 2 is visible depending on what radio button is clicked.

I did some research into this - what is my best way of doing this? the following things came in my mind, without too much code:

- create ALL dropdowns into the main form and put each pair inside a groupbox. Then depending on which radio button is clicked, change the `Visible` property to true/false on that specefic groupbox. **(so there will be like 30+ groupbox stacked on top of each other in the main form but with visibility set to false). Is this an issue? will it make the main form laggy/slow if there is so many elements stacked on top of each other? is there any flaws this way?**
- Another way I thought I could do it is have only 2-3 dropdowns in my form and dynamically update the selectable values inside the same dropdown, so that the value/options are fed dynamically and are relavent to the radio button clicked. This way there will only be a total of 2-3 dropdowns in the main form but their values get changed real time constantly.

I'm not sure if someone with a lot more experience than me can point out the answer or better way?

Comment: Just build a class that maps a RadioButton to a list of choices and use only two Controls that show the related lists of values.

Comment: The first *option* is a nightmare in all departments.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course you should do it dynamically, it will be much easier when updating or editing your code.

Comment: Hi, i was mainly asking about two things, which one is better for performance/"lighter" and is it 'correct' way of doing it

Comment: Yes, I recommend the Dynamic Option, will be much lighter and the performance depends on how much effort will be spent to collect data sources, but in general performance should not be affected

Comment: And In general, Less Code usually means More Performance